# Win 2008 R2 and samba

Tags: samba, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a problem accessing a samba share from a windows 2008 R2. All the shares on the samba server are perfectly ok excepted one. Accessing the same faulty share from a 2008 32 bits or any other xp or 2003 works smoothly... Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

It's because 2008 R2 (or Windows 7) is requiring NTLM v2, which your Samba doesn't do.  To make NTLM v2 optional use the following regedit:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters DWORD RequireSignOrSeal = 0
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters DWORD RequireStrongKey = 0
```

Possibly upgrading to Samba [3.43](http://www.samba.org/samba/history/samba-3.4.3.html) will fix this without the regedit.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I changed the registry and rebooted. But I still can't access the share... What's strange is I don't have an error in samba's log file. Any other idea?

Comment: Which Samba version?